# Как проверить форму, что она является объектом PostForm

Tags: python

[image: подскажите ак проверить форму, что она является объектом PostForm]

подскажите как проверить форму, что она является объектом PostForm

Answer (score 0):

```
def test_forms_show_correct(self):
    """Проверка коректности формы."""
    pages_forms = {
        reverse('posts:post_create'),
        reverse('posts:post_edit', kwargs={'post_id': self.post.id, }),
    }
    for value in pages_forms:
        with self.subTest(value=value):
            response = self.authorized_client.get(value)
            self.assertIsInstance(
                response.context.get('form'),
                PostForm)
            self.assertIsInstance(
                response.context.get('form').fields.get('text'),
            forms.fields.CharField)
            self.assertIsInstance(
                response.context.get('form').fields.get('group'),
                forms.fields.ChoiceField)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите